# How common are ticket checks on the Rhônexpress tram in Lyon?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, lyon

The Rhônexpress tram in Lyon, running from the city centre to the airport, costs 13.20 euros.

However, how easy is it to evade the fare? Are there barriers at the stations, and how common is it for inspections to take place?

Comment: Are you asking how easy is it to evade the fare?

Comment: @Berwyn Correct

Comment: You are asking for advice on how to commit a crime?!

Comment: @Moo In many areas, evading the fare on public transportation is considered a "misdemeanor" rather than a crime. Getting caught doing this will (mostly) not involve regular police, nor give you a criminal record. It's often considered similar to getting a parking ticket. [Some people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planka.nu) also claim they are doing this as a sort of activism (whereas others would, of course, say that they are just cheapskates looking for an excuse not to pay.)

Comment: @Fiksdal mere semantics on the level of the crime, I would still call it committing a crime and unacceptable.

Comment: @Moo Yeah, mostly semantics. But in some countries, criticizing the rulers or leaving a religion are also crimes. So I think something being against laws/regulations is in itself not enough to deem it unacceptable. It comes down to individual ethical considerations. Like certain types of online piracy.

Comment: @Fiksdal you arent really comparing the evasion of a fare for a legitimate service in a western country to that of religious fanaticism or dictatorial rule?

Comment: @Moo Sure, yeah, but only as an extreme example. I'm **not** saying that fares on public transportation (whether they occur in a "western, democratic" (what does that even mean?) country or not) is some sort of draconian (or even negative at all) imposition comparable to extremist laws of suppressive regimes. Of course, I believe that the latter suck and the former are quite alright. I was simply using it as an extreme example (a quite common rhetorical device) to show that illegality itself is not a criteria to say that something is immoral....

Comment: Thus, the argument “doing X is wrong *because it is illegal*" is invalid, because not all laws are morally sound. Even "Western democracies" can have immoral laws. The rule that everyone has to pay their fare is probably not an example of that. However, we can instead say "evading the fare is immoral because [insert ethical consideration here]." Thus we have an ethical reason rather than a blind reliance on laws. [Fare evasion is socially accepted to some degree in France.](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/6b25c94e-da14-11e4-ab32-00144feab7de.html)

Comment: -1, if you use public transport you pay for it, it is that simple. If you do not and others also do not, they make it much harder for all people to use it with those nasty barriers and ticket inspections. Be fair, pay for what you use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not give advice on how to break the law.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do not live in Lyon, but I took the Rhone Express 4 times recently.

My ticket was checked every time. I am pretty sure there's a 100% chance you will encounter an officer. If you are found without a ticket, you will be asked to buy one on the spot, along  with a 1€ tax.

Comment: @MarkSegal not at a 100% chance for it to happen. It needs to drop to 93% to statistically be worth the risk.

Answer (score 8):

There's a conductor in every train and he will for sure check your ticket.
I've already seen 2 or 3 guys being arrested by the police at the terminus station because they didn't want to pay the regular fare.

Answer (score 5):

Every Rhônexpress tram has a steward, and they will check every passenger, every time. If you get on the tram without a ticket, [you will need to buy it from the steward, and pay an extra transaction fee of €4, regardless of the number of tickets you bought](https://www.rhonexpress.fr/en/where-to-buy-tickets/53).